# Remove whitespace in title in moderncv (banking) style

Tags: spacing, white-space

I would like to remove the whitespace that appears between the address line and the line below with the phone numbers and email information on.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}           

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}            

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                             
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}                         

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

I've tried using vspace with a negative value but haven't been able to make this work.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3,postcode}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345}
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{%
\\\null}{%
\\[-2ex]\null}{}{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]